# C# IronRuby call ruby script with arguments

Tags: c#, ruby, ironruby

I'm trying to call a ruby script from my c# program. I found some documentation on the IronRuby package and started using that, however I've run into some problems with the command line arguments. The script must take two arguments to work properly. I can't seem to figure out how to get the c# program to understand that I'm passing arguments and a file, not just a file path. Here is my code:

```
 var runtime = Ruby.CreateRuntime();
 var engine = runtime.GetEngine("rb");
 var arg1 = "arg1";
 var arg2 = "arg2";
 String path = String.Format(@"{0} {1} {2}", @"filepath", arg1, arg2);
 engine.ExecuteFile(path);
```

Comment: Surrounding parameters with single quotes should help: `String.Format(@"{0} '{1}' '{2}'", @"filepath", arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: The same error occurs - cannot find file "file path 'arg1' 'arg2'"